# Why does my linting configuration for a React app want double quotes instead of single?

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I am having trouble diagnosing an oddity in my linting configuration. It wants me to use double quotes, which I wouldn't necessarily mind, but I can't understand *why* because as far as I can tell all my rules want singles.

This is for a React app. My setup uses ESLint with Airbnb and Prettier. I installed packages according to tutorials and the documentation for the involved plugins. I am editing with VSCode.

I have the following relevant packages in `package.json` (in project root):

```json
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "prettier": "^1.17.1",
```

And I have the following in `.eslintrc.json` (also in the project root). This includes some custom rules I have specified for my project.

```js
{
    "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
    "plugins": ["react", "jest", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [".js", "jsx"]
            }
        ],
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "class-methods-use-this": 0,
        "no-else-return": 0,
        "no-plusplus": [2, { "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true }],
        "no-param-reassign": 0,
        "no-use-before-define": ["error",  { "functions": false }],
        "import/no-named-as-default": 0
```

My primary question: why does it show single quotes as errors?

Is this due to a rule somewhere in my configuration that I am unaware of? Did I fail to include one of the plugins properly?

I know some rules might want double quotes in JSX, but this complains about double quotes *anywhere*.

Currently, I am not using any `.jsx` files.

Screenshots:

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

[Complete project on GitHub](https://github.com/cdpautsch/react-learning-area/tree/master/test-app2)

[Edit 6/3/19] I might have found some info, but I'm still a little confused... Reading the [`eslint-config-prettier` documentation](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#quotes), does this mean that double quotes are actually the default? But according to official [Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes), single quotes should be the default, right? Am I reading this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I believe, a fundamental misunderstanding of the Prettier defaults; it *does* want double quotes, not singles, but I had misread it as the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `quotes` option instead of `prettier`? so that you can explicitly tell eslint you want to use single quotes in JS.

```
"quotes": ["error", "single"]
```

And you can use the following setting if you want to use double quotes in JSX.

```
"jsx-quotes": ["error", "prefer-double"]
```

I am using both in the project I am working on, so far no problem. Hope it helps.